# Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have this entities:

```
Invoice hasMany PlannedCharge
PlannedCharge hasMany PartialCharge
```

I need to know if a invoice is totally paid, as does the following sql:

```
SELECT 
    Invoice.id
FROM
    webfactory_sale_invoices Invoice
    AND
        0 <> 
        ((SELECT 
            SUM(PlannedCharge.ammount)
        FROM
            webfactory_sale_planned_charges PlannedCharge
        WHERE
            PlannedCharge.invoice_id = Invoice.id
        GROUP BY Invoice.id) - IFNULL((SELECT 
            SUM(PartialCharge.ammount)
        FROM
            webfactory_sale_planned_charges PlannedCharge
                INNER JOIN
            webfactory_sale_partial_charges PartialCharge ON PlannedCharge.id = PartialCharge.planned_charge_id
        WHERE
            PlannedCharge.invoice_id = Invoice.id
        GROUP BY Invoice.id), 0))
```

Now, translating to DQL through the querybuilder with this way:

```
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->neq(0, $qb->expr()->diff(
    $qb->select('SUM(PlannedCharge.ammount)')
            ->from('WebFactorySaleBundle:PlannedCharge', 'PlannedCharge')
            ->where("PlannedCharge.invoice = {$invoiceAlias}")
            ->groupBy($invoiceAlias)
            , 
    $qb->select('SUM(PartialCharge.ammount)')
            ->from('WebFactorySaleBundle:PlannedCharge', 'PlannedCharge')
            ->innerJoin('WebFactorySaleBundle:PartialCharge', 'PartialCharge')
            ->where("PlannedCharge.invoice = {$invoiceAlias}")
            ->groupBy($invoiceAlias)
    )
));
```

i get the error message: Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

How i can write this query?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it more like this:

```
SELECT 
    i.id, sum_planned, sum_partial, sum_planned - ifnull(sum_partial,0) AS saldo
FROM
    (SELECT id
    FROM webfactory_sale_invoices
    GROUP BY id
    ) i LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         id, SUM(ammount) AS sum_planned
    FROM
        webfactory_sale_planned_charges 
    GROUP BY 
        id) pl ON 
        i.id = pl.id LEFT OUTER JOIN        
    (SELECT 
        id, SUM(ammount) AS sum_partial
    FROM
        webfactory_sale_partial_charges 
    GROUP BY 
        id) pa ON i.id = pa.id
```

Comment: Is my way too, but doctrine2 do not support this feature.

Comment: ah, sry.  not my sql, then.  Can you get rid of the join between partial and planned charges?  However you can simplify it should help.